Normal r.v. convergence in law to a normal r.v. implies convergence of mean and variance
Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of normal random variables with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma_n^2$ for $n\ge 0$ respectively. If $X_n \implies X_0,\ (convergence \ in\  law)$ then $\mu_n \to \mu_0$ and $\sigma_n^2 \to \sigma_0^2.$
This is immediate using characteristic functions; but I am interested in solving without the aid of chf. I tried approaching using Baby Skorohod's but was not able to conclude as the functions are not bounded.
This is part of Resnick's chap 8 exercise question.

The $X_n$ having normal distributions is important; otherwise there could be counter-examples.

@Henry True, indeed the assumption of the sequence and X should be of same dist. to make such a statement.

Because the standard normal cdf is one-to-one, if $X_n$ converges in law to $X$ then $(x-\mu_n)/\sigma_n\to(x-\mu)/\sigma$ for all real $x$. That's a lot of information to work with!

Thanks for the hint!

Awesome! Also in the same question, Resnick follows up by posing the similar question for Poisson and Exponential. In the Poisson case, this would not work.

Exponential would be similar because of the explicit formula for the cdf in that case. What would you do in the Poisson case?

Use Continuity theorem on the function e^-tX, t>0 in the Poisson case. By virtue of boundedness we get the desired conclusion.

Or use
$$
e^{-\lambda_n}=\Bbb[X_n=0]=\Bbb P[X_n\le 1/2]\to\Bbb P[X\le 1/2]=\Bbb P[X=0]=e^{-\lambda}.
$$

I got into thinking only with the bounded functions and the continuity theorem(my bad).  Yes it follows straight from the definition. Thanks for the follow up @JohnDawkins

Let $N$ be a standard normal rv. We have
$$\Bbb P\!\left(N>\frac{t-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)=\Bbb P(X_n>t)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\Bbb P(X_0>t)$$
and therefore
$$\limsup_{t\to\infty}\:\limsup_{n\to\infty}\:\Bbb P\!\left(N>\frac{t-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)=0.\tag{$\star$}$$
If we had $\mu_n\to\infty$ along a subsequence, then $t-\mu_n<0$ would hold for infinitely many $n$ and we would have $$\Bbb P\!\left(N>\frac{t-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)\ge\Bbb P(N>0)=\frac12,$$
which contradicts $(\star)$.
This proves that $(\mu_n)$ must be bounded from above. Replacing $X_n$ by $-X_n$, we deduce that $(\mu_n)$ must also be bounded from below. But then (for the same reason), $(\star)$ cannot hold if $\sigma_n\to\infty$ along a subsequence. Thus $(\mu_n)$ and $(\sigma_n)$ must both be bounded. Now, along any converging subsequence $(\mu_n,\sigma_n)\to(\mu,\sigma)$, we end up with
$$\forall t\in\Bbb R,\quad \Bbb P\!\left(N>\frac{t-\mu_0}{\sigma_0}\right) = \Bbb P\!\left(N>\frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\!,$$
which shows that the only limit for $(\mu_n,\sigma_n)$ is $(\mu_0,\sigma_0)$.

I haven't thought this way. Its clear now.
